# Browser connection okay but Cloud Station not connecting on a Synology NAS

Tags: internet-connection, synology, owncloud

It seems that I have to modify the network connection for a local Synology NAS client (Cloud Station) for getting it work.

I’m a proud owner of a Synology DS215j NAS.

Basically almost everything works fine, the only worry is the Cloud Station (file sharing service that works kind of like Dropbox) on my office PC.

**Problem**: When I’m connecting the laptop at home to the internet, everything works fine. However in the office the cloud station isn't syncing. I can’t establish a connection to the NAS but the connection through the browser (Firefox and Internet Explorer) is working properly.

**Settings in CloudStation Client**: Settings for the proxy in the CloudStation client is set to auto identify the proxy settings. I’ve no cloud which settings I’ve to set manually (IP and port) for the proxy that we’re using. The internet settings (Internet Explorer) are set to “connection script” with link to .pac file, Firefox to “use settings of system.”

**Settings in DSM (DiskStation Manager, the Synology NAS OS)**: System works fine. No problem for connection to Cloud Station at home with my computer or with my iPhone at any time. If also activated in the DSM the checkbox for abandoning the verification of the IP under Settings > Security. But it didn’t help.

How I can get the CloudStation client working in my office? Do I have tto modify the client somehow in another way?

Comment: It could just be your place of employment's Internet not allowing data over the port the application uses. I would advise you to ask the IT desk at your place of work (if you can).

Answer (score 0):

You have most probably configured everything correctly!
Actually, in our office we also have that problem over and over again. 
Sometimes it works (in the LAN), sometimes - all of a sudden - the connection breaks.
This is critical for companies as they rely on their Cloud drive.

The solution, which works for us (but is far from perfect) is a daily reboot of the Synology. You can set that in the Control panel >> Task planner >> Add 2 tasks: 1 for shutdown at some time during the night and 5 minutes later another task for starting again.

The naming of the "Control panel", etc may be wrong, I have a German version and just guessed the namings.